# Как проверить, является аргумент по умолчанию в шаблоне или нет?

Tags: c++

Я хочу вызывать функцию без дополнительных аргументов, но мне нужно добавить проверку внутри функции, что бы узнать был добавлен аргумент по умолчанию или нет.

```
  template <class T1, class T2>
    void NumbVector(T1& int_numb = 1, T2& string_numb) {
    
        // проверку желательно сделать на уровне if
        if (?) {
            
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

сам вызов

```
NumbVector(10, 3);
NumbVector(1);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137317/discussion-on-question-by-sffff-------).

Comment: ну вот. ну зачем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример

```
// эта функция содержит всю логику
// можно сказать, что оно "приватная"
// n - это дополнительный парамер
template <class T1, class T2>
void NumbVector(T1& int_numb, T2& string_numb, int n) {

    if (n == 1) {
        // позвали функцию с одним параметром
    } else {
        // позвали функцию с двумя параметрами
    }

    
}

// это функция с двумя параметрами
template <class T1, class T2>
void NumbVector2(T1& int_numb, T2& NumbVector) {
    // 2 в параметре как раз и означает, что вызывается функция с двумя параметрами
    // но это условность. Можно прицепить bool, можно enum.
    NumbVector(int_numb, NumbVector, 2);
    
}
// а это - с одним
template <class T1, class T2>
void NumbVector1(T2& string_numb) {
    // а тут вот так пришлось, потому что параметр передается по ссылке.
    // может это ошибка, а может это так и задумано
    int x = 1;
    NumbVector(x, string_numb, 1);
    
}
```

потом можно пойти дальше и прикрутить std::forward, а может использовать variadic template. Но нужно ли это?

Возможно, Ваша задача сильно проще и есть более красивые решения.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать теперь)

Comment: это называется "любую проблему можно решить дополнительным уровнем вложенности кроме большого количества их"

Comment: Но это по сути то же самое, что и указывать в вызове в виде дополнительного параметра, идет ли в функции аргумент по умолчанию или нет. Просто таким параметром теперь служит 1 и 2 в имени функции, нет?

Comment: я думаю, что автор вопроса не знал, что можно одинаковый код вынести в отдельную функцию. И всех делов то.

Comment: Интересна позиция минусаторов.

Comment: @KoVadim а ты просто доработает ответ, сделай его более автономным и будет пушка.
Смысли что бы каждый раз не писать в функцию дополнительные аргументы.

Comment: Люди просто не шарят, на самом деле в этом решении чет есть, он упрощает частично шаблоны, если доработать.

Comment: Если бы ответ был "этого нельзя сделать", то он бы отвечал заданному вопросу, хотя по формату скорее годился бы для комментария. Не знаю, как вы, но я регулярно сам ищу ответы на SO. И ситуация, когда находишь вопрос, а ответ в нем не соответствует заголовку (даже если был удовлетворительным для ОПа), очень раздражает.

Comment: я вот как раз на это и отвечал на мете.  Люди слишком разные. И по виду и по знаниям. Ответ, который будет очень хорош для новичка, будет выглядеть недостойным для "крутого" (который таким не является:) ). Вот этот вопрос как раз таким и есть. И что бы понять ответ, нужно ответить для себя в стиле "вам шашечки или ехать?". И вот тут как раз я пишу о "ехать", а минусаторы хотят "шашечки". Так что минусаторы идут гулять, раз они не могут понять, что есть и простые люди, которые только начали свой путь и не все могут понять.

Comment: Если собираетесь раздавать советы и завуалированные оскорбления, то следует поискать в интернете другой ресурс.